# Prove that if quantum operators $[A, B]$ do not commute then $[A^2, B^2]$ also does not commute

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, commutator

How to prove that if quantum operators $[A, B]$ do not commute then $[A^2, B^2]$ also does not commute? Given for example $[L_x, L_y].$

Comment: Do you mean if $A,\,B$ don't commute neither do $A^2,\,B^2$? If so, this would be stated as if $[A,\,B]\ne0$ then $[A^2,\,B^2]\ne0$. (This is false in general though, because [e.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) $\sigma_1\sigma_2=-\sigma_2\sigma_1=i\sigma_3$ but $\sigma_1^2=\sigma_2^2=I_2$.) Is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) that you want to prove e.g. $[L_x^2,\,L_y^2]\ne0$?

Comment: Did you try using the identity $[A,BC] = [A,B]C+B[A,C]$?

Comment: @J.G. Yes that is what I actually want to prove. However, I thought I could generalize it. Thank you for noting that it wont hold for all A, B.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use product rule for commutators: $[X,Y Z] = Y[X,Z] + [X,Y] Z$ (note the order!).

Thus:
$$[A^2,B^2] = A[A,B^2] + [A,B^2] A = A B [A,B] + A[A,B] B + B [A,B] A+ [A,B] B A = 0 $$ if $[A,B] = 0$ in general.

However, a quick counterexample shows that your conjecture does not hold: $[A,B] \neq 0$ *does not imply* that $[A^2,B^2] \neq 0$. Take e.g. Pauli matrices $A=\sigma^x$ and $B=\sigma^y$, so that $[A,B] = i \sigma^z$. On the other hand, $(\sigma^x)^2 = (\sigma^y)^2 = I$ so that $[A^2,B^2] = [I,I] = 0$.